# Querying many-to-many relationship in Laravel while limiting relation existence

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following models in laravel:

```
TheJobs
- id
- description
- created_at
- deleted_at
- updated_at

TheSeries
- id
- title
- description
- created_at
- deleted_at
- updated_at


TheMovies
- id
- title
- description
- created_at
- deleted_at
- updated_at


mSeriesJobs
- seriesID
- jobID

mMoviesJobs
- movieID
- jobID
```

Here are the relationships for `TheJobs`:

```
 public function TheSeries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\TheSeries', 'mSeriesJobs', 'jobID', 'seriesID');
  }

  public function TheMovies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\TheMovies', 'mMoviesJobs', 'jobID', 'movieID');
  }
```

Here are the relationships for `TheSeries`:

```
  public function TheJobs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\TheJobs', 'mSeriesJobs', 'seriesID', 'jobID');
  }
```

same for Movies.

I would like to :

- get all `TheSeries` jobs.
- get all `TheMovies` jobs.
- get all the Jobs with `TheSeries` or `TheMovies` data.

## To clarify the question:

I need a simple Eloquent query which will select all `TheSeries` which have at least one `TheJobs`.

Comment: can you post the relationship methods also?

Comment: @xhulio just updated

Comment: can you also explain a little bit what you want to retrieve? i mean what conditions should the collection returned satisfy

Comment: when you say `TheSeries` jobs, you mean only the series collection or a manipulated collection?

Comment: @xhulio, no conditions at all, what I need is described in the question (updated now). Just retrieve all TheJobs which are linked to `TheSeries` for the start.

Comment: When I say TheSeries jobs, means that I want to get the `TheJobs` which are associated with `TheSeries`

Comment: What's the relation between 'theSeries' and 'theSeriesEpisodes'? I think it would help if you standarise your model names,i.e. remove "the" and use singular word for model names.

Comment: Just fixed it, it's actually `TheSeries`

Comment: In your current code, there is still a mix of 'Episode' and 'Series'. Does that cause the break?? If I understand correctly, they are the same thing. That's to say, only 3 models in question here: Movie, Series, Job.

Comment: @JohnDoe, yes only 3 models:  Movies, Series, Jobs. I am trying to prevent this: Movies, Series, MoviesJobs, SeriesJobs as they have common columns.

Comment: also, `App\Models\TheJobs` should be `App\TheJobs` unless you have defined your own model directory structure...

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered, I believe you are looking for "Querying Relationship Existence", i.e. (wording from Laravel Doc) accessing the records for a model, while limiting the results based on the existence of a relationship.

In this case, if you need a simple Eloquent query which will select all `TheSeries` that have at least one `TheJobs`, I believe you can try `has`:

```
$TheSeries = App\TheSeries::has('TheJobs')->get();
```

The other way should work too, for jobs:

```
$TheJobs = App\TheJobs::has('TheSeries')->get();
```

Assumption: all model relations have been properly defined.

You can find more about "has" here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships (Search in-page for "Querying Relationship Existence" please.)

Answer (score 0):

in Job model:

```
public function series()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Series');
}
```

Series model:

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job');
}
```

get all TheSeries jobs:

```
$series = Series::whereHas('jobs')->get();
$seriesJob = $series->jobs;
```

Comment: I need all jobs for `TheSeries`, this will not work.

Comment: This will find all the Jobs for Series.id = 1. I need for all series which have at least a job.

Comment: All the raws are soft-deleted, how will i retrieve them?

Comment: @PHPLover using `->trashed()` method

Comment: you can try to change the deleted_at column on your database to null. this will make them all available.

Comment: @OdinThunder, the first line works (whereHas) it returns successfully the series which have a job, but the second line doesnot work to display jobs data.

Comment: @PHPLover thats because he is calling `$job-?jobs` where he should call `$series->jobs`;

Comment: sorry, my mistake :(

Comment: @OdinThunder, I didn't observe the issue, however I did it right when testing. It doesnt work because you can not take jobs $series which is not one-object.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to do this. the first one is using eloquent relationships like you have started. in order to get all the jobs of a series all you have to do is:

```
$seriesCollection = TheSeries::all();
$seriesCollection->TheJobs();
```

The second method is better in my opinion. You will use accessors in order to retrieve what you want. 
So in the series model, to get all the jobs related to a series just do the following:

```
public function getSeriesJobsAttribute(){
    $job_series = DB::table('mSeriesJobs')->where('seriesID', $this->attributes['id'])->get(['jobID']);
    $job = TheJobs::whereIn('id', $job_series)->get();
    return $job;
}
```

and then in your view just iterate through `$seriesCollection->series_jobs` while in your controller you only retrieve the `$seriesCollection`;

Comment: When i try your first example, it says `TheJobs()` method doesn't exist :(

Comment: you should include that method on your series model

Comment: I did include, but it doesn't work since there are more then one records.

Comment: It looks messy to me for a simple task as this, but will try it now.

Comment: It does work without any doubt, just tried it. But I need to use the models i have.

Comment: Interesting, I thought accessors are only used for mutating individual database records.

Comment: @JohnDoe actually they can be used for more than that :) I stumbled upon this accidentally and I was surprised as well.